# How to extract only a fragment of composite type

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have the following SQL code that does some spatial operations of PostGIS in PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT 
ST_Dump(
    ST_SymDifference(a.geom, b.geom) 
)
FROM smp_areas a, smp_areas b
```

It returns for me in a format of a composite type, composed of two parts:

[image: output]

How to get only the second part (that, in this case, contains the geometry that I need)?

Ps: I've read that re-arranging like the following would work:

```
SELECT * FROM( myquery ) as alias;
```

I tried but returned the same result.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the geometry, you need to put extra parenthesis around the [ST_Dump()](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html) and add the `.geom`. Like this:

```
SELECT 
(ST_Dump(
    ST_SymDifference(a.geom, b.geom) 
)).geom
FROM smp_areas a, smp_areas b
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you wrap that query in something like

```
Select * from (my query) as alias where geometry_dump 
Like '{2}%'
```

P.s. the above is sql server format so may not directly translate to postgres.